# How to search for strings in the output of previously run commands

Tags: terminal, command-history, search, stdout, output

Say, for example that after running a number of commands:

```
$ cd /opt/something
$ find . -name *aa | grep 11 
$ clear  
$ <more commands go here>
```

there was a part of the output that was needed but not saved; the command which produced it as well as the arguments might not be recalled entirely.

Is there a way to search through `stdout` (even though `clear` may have been called several times).

Comment: If this is a continuing issue, you might check out `man script`. Or just don't `clear` until you are sure you don't need the immediate terminal stdout history. I also keep a side window running `cat` so I can paste in commands I might want to repeat.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

stdout is transient, or ephemeral.  Unless you take some action to save it, it's gone and inaccessible as soon as it's output.

If you want to re-use the output of a command multiple times, then you need to save it somewhere - a scalar variable (e.g. with [command substitution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Command_substitution)), an array variable (e.g. with `readarray`/`mapfile`), or a file (e.g. with redirection or `tee`).

When working with filenames, you should always use NUL as the separator, as **all** other  characters are valid characters in pathnames (most common tools these days have a `-0`, `-z`, `-Z`, or similar option for working with NUL-separated input & output).  This means that it's unsafe to use command substitution with `find` (although it's fine with other programs that produce text that isn't filenames).

e.g.

```
find . name '*aa' -print0 > files.list0
grep -z 11 files.list0
```

or

```
readarray -d '' -t files < <(find . -name '*aa' -print0)
printf '%s\0' "${files[@]}" | grep -z 11
```

---

BTW, the `*aa` should be quoted in that `find` command, otherwise the shell will expand it to all matching files (and only the first will belong to the `-name` predicate, the rest will be errors).